# Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a jQuery date picker control that works fine for once instance, but I'm not sure how to get it to work for multiple instances.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#my_date').datepicker();
    });
</script>

<% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
<% For Each item In Model.MyRecords%>
<%=Html.TextBox("my_date")%> <br/>
<% Next%>
<% End Using%>
```

Without the For Each loop, it works fine, but if there's more than one item in the "MyRecords" collection, then only the first text box gets a date picker (which makes sense since it's tied to the ID). I tried assigning a class to the text box and specifying:

```
$('.my_class').datepicker();
```

but while that shows a date picker everywhere, they all update the first text box.

What is the right way to make this work?

Comment: What language is the <% blah %> stuff?

Comment: That's VB inside an ASP.NET page - just a quick way to illustrate the point of the question.

Comment: Ensure the input fields are not `disabled`, the datepicker won't show up for input fields with the `disabled` attribute

Answer (score 132, accepted):

html:

```
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_1" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_2" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_3" />
```

script:

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

(pseudo coded up a bit to keep it simpler)

Comment: It looks like the heart of my problem is that the text boxes all have the same ID, so every date picker is updating the first text box. Your example doesn't suffer from that, so it works. How do I get the ID's to be different in a loop?

Comment: Duh, don't let the text boxes have the same ID. Sometimes you have to step away from a problem for a while for the obvious answer to bubble up.

Comment: Wouldn't `$(".datepick").datepicker();` work once you have different ids on the input fields?

Comment: I didn't have ID's on the inputs but had the same class. Work ok on Chrome and FF but not IE. To fix I just get the inputs ID's

Comment: I have attached datepicker to some HTML textboxes using CSS class name & `onSelect` event handler I need to know the selector class name on which current `onSelect` happened.. the elements have 2 other classes applied other then the one I am using to attach datepicker

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same problem.

The correct way to use date pick is `$('.my_class').datepicker();` but you need to make sure you don't assign the same ID to multiple datepickers.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious answer would be to generate different ids, a separate id for each text box, something like

```
[int i=0]
<% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
<% For Each item In Model.MyRecords%>
[i++]
<%=Html.TextBox("my_date[i]")%> <br/>
<% Next%>
<% End Using%>
```

I don't know ASP.net so I just added some general C-like syntax code within square brackets. Translating it to actual ASP.net code shouldn't be a problem.

Then, you have to find a way to generate as many

```
$('#my_date[i]').datepicker();
```

as items in your `Model.MyRecords`. Again, within square brackets is your counter, so your jQuery function would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#my_date1').datepicker();
        $('#my_date2').datepicker();
        $('#my_date3').datepicker();
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
 <!-- jQuery JS Includes -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/ui.datepicker.js"></script>

 <!-- jQuery CSS Includes -->
 <link type="text/css" href="jquery/themes/base/ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link type="text/css" href="jquery/themes/base/ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link type="text/css" href="jquery/themes/base/ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <!-- Setup Datepicker -->
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  $(function() {
   $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'jquery/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true
   });
  });
 --></script>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Each input field needs a unique id, but all need to be datepicker -->
 <p>Date 1: <input id="one" class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>
 <p>Date 2: <input id="two" class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>
 <p>Date 3: <input id="three" class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>      
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"> </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/flexcroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/JScript.js"></script>
        <title>calendar</title>    
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){$('.dateTxt').datepicker(); }); 
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Date 1: <input id="one" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
        <p>Date 2: <input id="two" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
        <p>Date 3: <input id="three" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When adding datepicker at runtime generated input textboxes you have to check if it already contains datepicker then first remove class hasDatepicker then apply datePicker to it.

```
function convertTxtToDate() {
        $('.dateTxt').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
            } 
             $(this).datepicker();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*A little note to the SeanJA answer.*

Interestingly, if you use **KnockoutJS and jQuery together** 
the following inputs **with different IDs**, but with **the same data-bind observable**:

```
<data-bind="value: first_dt" id="date_1" class="datepick" />
<data-bind="value: first_dt" id="date_2" class="datepick" />
```

will bind one (the same) datepicker to both of the inputs (even though they have different ids or names).

Use **separate observables in your ViewModel** to bind a separate datepicker to each input:

```
<data-bind="value: first_dt" id="date_1" class="datepick" />
<data-bind="value: second_dt" id="date_2" class="datepick" />
```

Initialization:

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: You should never work that way in combination with KnockoutJS. It's way better and cleaner if you bind your datepicker using a bindingHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to have different IDs as many of you have stated. The problem still lies deeper in datepicker. Please correct me, but doesn't the datepicker have one wrapper ID - "ui-datepicker-div." This is seen on http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOptions in the theming.

Is there an option that can change this ID to be a class? I don't want to have to fork this script just for this one obvious fix!!

Comment: That may just be the "sample" part of the sample code. I don't think it actually generates a div with that ID. Making sure each of my target objects had unique ID's made everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To change use of class instead of ID

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
        $('.my_date1').datepicker(); 
        $('.my_date2').datepicker(); 
        $('.my_date3').datepicker(); 
        ... 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: And surely we wouldn't want alternate approaches... although I admit that while this would work, I wouldn't use it. Especially after seeing the accepted answer - but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but finally discovered that it was an issue with the way I was invoking the script from an ASP web user control. I was using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`, but forgot to give the script a unique key (the second argument). With both scripts being assigned the same key, only the first box was actually being converted into a datepicker. So I decided to append the textbox's ID to the key to make it unique:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DPSetup" + DPTextbox.ClientID, dpScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with dynamically adding datepicker classes.  The solution I found was to comment out line 46 of datepicker.js

```
// this.element.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not given my `<input>` elements any ID, and was using a class to apply the datepicker as in SeanJA's answer, but the datepicker was only being applied to the first one. I discovered that JQuery was automatically adding an ID and it was the same one in all of the elements, which explained why only the first was getting datepickered.