# Multiple instances of jQuery DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is how I define my datetime picker

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'y-m-d',
    timeFormat: 'h:m:s'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="branch">
    <h2>Branch 1</h2>
    <input id="from" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="from"/>
    <input id="to" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="to"/>
   </div>
   <div class="branch">
    <h2>Branch 2</h2>
    <input id="from" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="from"/>
    <input id="to" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="to"/>
   </div>
```

This works for the fields in branch 1. Have a look at the following picture:

[image]

The top two fields get their date correctly. But when I focus the bottom input field and set a date, not the bottom field is set but the top field. This is wrong, the bottom field should get the date.

I cannot access each input field by id because the input field is created dynamically and there are many of them. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the whole code, where you create your inputs and activate the datetimepicker?

Comment: If you cannot use the id's then use an attribute selector.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs, that's not valid HTML.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is because you're re-using the same id's in a page and id should be unique

Comment: Great, this is obviously an dublicated ID problem

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use the same id on an html element more than one time at the same page. Look at your `<input id="from" ...` and `<input id="to" ...`

```
<div class="branch">
    <h2>Branch 1</h2>
    <input id="from_1" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="from"/>
    <input id="to_1" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="to"/>
   </div>
   <div class="branch">
    <h2>Branch 2</h2>
    <input id="from_2" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="from"/>
    <input id="to_2" class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="to"/>
   </div>
```

This should fix your datepicker issue.