# Is it possible to instantiate all datetimepicker's with one javascript call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have PHP generating a random amount of ***bootstrap-datetimepicker*** widgets, and I'm trying to instantiate them with one jQuery function, rather than one for each.

They all have the class `.datepicker`, but

```
$(function () {
   $('.datepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

does not work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I just tried

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).datetimepicker();
    });
});
```

however, I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateOptions' of null`.

EDIT: Fixed.

Hi,

I am working on a legacy codebase, and was using the wrong jQuery to instantiate.  Everything works with the latest jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290139/multiple-instances-of-jquery-datetime-picker check this if it helps

Comment: can you add your example html or php code which is generating