# having trouble with bootstrap datepicker to work in button of Gridview Edit modal of Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

bootstrap datepicker does not work in bootstrap modal, it is assigned to a Button of Gridview. I have another button not in Gridview, when I click it Bootstrap modal works fine and Bootstrap Datepicker also works fine. Trouble is with the datepicker which is in Bootstrap modal of Edit buttons in Gridview.

```
    $(function () {
        $(".DatePickerControl").datepicker('setValue', '01/01/1985');
        $('.DatePickerControl').datepicker('update');
        $('.DatePickerControl').val('');
        /* $('#dp1').datepicker('setDate', new Date(1985, 01, 01));
        $('#dp1').datepicker('update');
        $('#dp1').val('');*/
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution from here

[How to apply jquery datepicker to textbox in gridview in masterpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428002/how-to-apply-jquery-datepicker-to-textbox-in-gridview-in-masterpage)

You need to insert the below code before UpdatePanel

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true">



</asp:ScriptManager>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(getme);
            function getme() {
                $('.DatePickerControl').datepicker('setValue', '01/01/1985');
                $('.DatePickerControl').datepicker('update');
                $('.DatePickerControl').val('');
            }
    </script>  

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="true"
```