# How to enter value of datepicker into text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I have a list of tasks and each task has an edit date option which I use jquery datepicker for.

This is my application.js:

```
$(function() {
   $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

This is my _edit_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for task do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: 'create a task' %>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :due_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :due_date, placeholder: 'select a date', class:"date", readonly: 'readonly' %>
  </div>
  <%= button_tag(type:'patch', class:"btn btn-default btn-xs") do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

So my problem is that datepicker only works for the first task on my list.  I can pick the date, it'll show up in the text field and it'll pass into my `task#update` controller just fine.

However, every task after that isn't able to receive input from datepicker.  The text field is blank when I select a date, and it doesn't pass into the controller.  When I debug in the web console, the 'value' = "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JQuery problem with using datepicker on multiple fields. It's not Rails's fault...

I think the answer you need is "[Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances)": attach a unique `id` to each field, then script the function as below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_1" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_2" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_3" />
```

Script:

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```