# JQuery Datepicker on multiple instances

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having a problem with JQuery date picker. I have a dynamically generated form with multiple date fields with Jquery Datepicker enabled. The date picker works on the first instance of the date field but doesn't work on the other ones. This is the code that I have:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker lenght" name="SubContractSubmitDate" id="SubContractSubmitDate" <?php echo "value='$SubContractSubmitDate' "; ?>  placeholder="">
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker lenght" name="SubContractSignedDate" id="SubContractSignedDate" <?php echo "value='$SubContractSignedDate' "; ?> placeholder="">
```

and then function that calls JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

I found this answer [Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances) but it still doesn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please, the PHP is irrelevant to your question. Also, have you checked the console for errors? Finally, are you calling `datepicker()` after your dynamically generated fields are added to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For  some reason the JQuery was not happy with my ids on the input elements. Even though the ids were unique they were causing the issue. I just removed id elements and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have dynamic element for datepicker try below.

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('focus','.datepicker', function() {
       $(this).datepicker();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Still the same result. The datepicker opens on click and I can select the date but the date is not entered into field. The first instance works with no problem.

Comment: I also used the following approach for toggle Jquery that worked. I am pretty sure that I need the same approach but I can't figure it out.

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".Panel").slideToggle("slow");

Comment: the IDs are different. they are very similar though

Comment: Oh my bad. try using updated answer and include the script at the bottom of html body. lmk how it goes.

Comment: I tried to paste the updated version and I moved it to the bottom of the document but still nothing. Should I somehow implement 'next' into the function?

Comment: Update your question with code for `.flip` element. and `.panel` html elements. i am confused about what is not working events you are trying or datepicker for all fields.