# Looping in php and incorporating Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, datetimepicker

I'm using datetimepicker javascript for bootstrap. The instance works if there is only one input field or if it's the first of multiple. But if there are multiple fields, the others don't work.

The widget is created from a foreach loop in php so foreach record it gives a new section with title, expiration date and a datetimepicker field to create a new date. However, if I hit the calendar icon of the 2nd or 3rd datepicker item it just activates the popover calendar for the first one.

How can i properly incorporate this into the loop so that each field has it's own input for datetimepicker?

```
<?php foreach($v as $k=>$n): ?>
<!--Body of the Modal for expired displays-->
<br>
<h6><?php echo $n['Type'] ?></h6>
<h6>Date/Time Expiring: <?php echo $n["Expiration"] ?></h6>
<h6>Set New Expiration:</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>                 
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     icons: {
                  time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                  date: "fa fa-calendar",
                  up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                  down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
              }
  });
});
</script>
```

UPDATE:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <div class=" datepicker input-group date"  data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target=".datepicker"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon" data-target=".datepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
  $(this).datetimepicker();
   icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: you're creating multiple `div`s with the same `id` (`"datetimepicker1"`). A possible solution is to keep a counter in your loop and use it as a suffix for the `id`s.

Comment: Don't put an ID in a loop, otherwise it's no longer unique. You could remove the datetimepicker1 ID, add a generic class like "datepicker" instead. Then in your JS target $('.datepicker') instead of the ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances)

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa I did this as well but now I get no pop ups. If I hit the calendar icon it just fills all boxes with today's date and time

Answer (score 0):

You have several div's with the same ID. This is not correct.

```
<?php foreach($v as $k=>$n): ?>
<!--Body of the Modal for expired displays-->
<br>
<h6><?php echo $n['Type'] ?></h6>
<h6>Date/Time Expiring: <?php echo $n["Expiration"] ?></h6>
<h6>Set New Expiration:</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>                 
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     icons: {
                  time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                  date: "fa fa-calendar",
                  up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                  down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
              }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would it maybe be better if I incorporated a php foreach loop around just the datepicker div and used an iterator to add a new ID to each one?

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker can't be run against a jQuery collection, you'll instead need to loop through with an .each callback. Change all ID's of "datetimepicker1" to be classes of "datepicker".

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Ok I changed this, you can see my updated code. Unfortunately, it still just populates every field with today's date if I click a calendar icon

Comment: Could it have to do with any of the data targets? @alexanderdesousa