# jquery Datepicker not working for html table rows except first row

Tags: jquery, html, .net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this html code in my .net MVC cshtml page. Datepicker class is used in input type for EventDate. Datepicker calendar is opening fine on each row when clicked on input textbox. The issue is, only first row textbox is getting filled with selected Date on calendar,  **the other rows are not filling up with selected date.**

```
$(function () {
    $(".Datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, 
        showAnim: "slideDown"
    });
});

    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables["dataa"].Rows)
                     {
                        <tr> 
                            <td>
                                <div class="editDelInput EventDateText">
                                    @row["EventDate"]  
                                </div>
                                <div class="saveCanInput EventDateInput" style="display:none">
                                    <input type="date" class="Datepicker form-control form-control-sm" id="NONUHCEventDate" name="NONUHCEventDate">
                                </div>
                            </td>
    </tr>
                     }
```

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using? It sounds like it only supports a single instance per page.

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js is that what are you asking ?

Comment: Not quite. That's your version of jQuery. I'm asking which DatePicker library you're using.

Comment: Not sure, How to check that ?

Comment: It will be somewhere in your HTML source, in a `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I assume your using [jQueryUI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

If your inputs have the same 'id' you probably find that no matter which date picker row you work with you are using the same instance which looks for the input with that id and happens to find the first input since the id is the same throughout the page.

The class="" alternative seems to be popular.

I have done similar things with VueJS, where I create a instance of VueJS per row.

This answer might help you.
[stackoverflow - Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances)

Comment: yes i am also referring .. https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: ok, so I removed the "id" from my control. and it worked with same code. Thanks.

Comment: A pleasure. Funny how as I posted my answer I got a immediate down vote from somewhere :)

Comment: You can keep the id, just make it unique by for example appending the unique @row db ID or maybe safer the foreach loop counter/index.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code.

> ```
> $(document).on('focus',".Datepicker").datepicker({
>         changeMonth: true,
>         changeYear: true, 
>         showAnim: "slideDown"
>     });
> ```