# How to generate selector name of datepicker from database?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

refer to:
[Apply jQuery datepicker to multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707603/apply-jquery-datepicker-to-multiple-instances)

I want to generate selector name of datepicker from database.

**Query from db:**

```
$query = "select id, name, ddate from db";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

**Results of query**:

```
id, name, ddate
001,Boy,2020-01-01
002,Roy,2020-02-01
003,Joy,2020-02-04
...
999,Tomy,2020-06-01
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="ddate" id="datepicker_$data_[id]" >
```

**Datepicker**:

```
<script>
...
$('#datepicker_$data_[id]').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  endDate: "0d"
})

</script>
```

In line `$('#datepicker_$data_[id]').datepicker`, i want to get `$data_[id]` value from database.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.

**HTML**
**change from:**

```
<input type="text" name="ddate" id="datepicker_$data_[id]" >
```

**to:**

```
<input type="text" name="ddate" class="edit-ddate" >
```

**Datepicker Change from**:

```
$('#datepicker_$data_[id]').datepicker({
...
...
})
```

**to:**

```
$('.edit-ddate').datepicker({
...
...
})
```